# How to limit the maximum number of files in the primeng FileUpload component?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

I have a [PrimeNg FileUpload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/fileupload) component and what I want is to limit the maximum amount of files that can be uploaded.

I tried to do it with the attribute `fileLimit` but it doesn't work.

```
 <p-fileUpload id="fileUploader" maxFileSize="{{ pesoMaximoArchivoDocumentacion }}"
            invalidFileSizeMessageDetail="{{ mensajeSuperaPeso }}" fileLimit="4"
            invalidFileTypeMessageDetail="{{ mensajeFormatoNoValido }}" *ngIf="isAttach(element.valor)"
            #fileUploader name="Files{{ i }}" id="{{ element.parametro }}" accept=".pdf" [auto]="true"
            [multiple]="isMultipleDoc(element.valor)" customUpload="true" (onSelect)="onSelect(fileUploader)"
            (uploadHandler)="
              onUploadConst($event, 1, fileUploader, element.valor)
            " chooseLabel="Adjuntar">
            <ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
              <div class="d-flex p-2 rounded align-items-center text-center flex-column flex-xl-row mb-3" [ngClass]="{
                  'btn-background-white': i % 2 == 0,
                  'btn-background-gray': i % 2 != 0
                }">
                <div class="ccb-cae-imagen-img-delete mr-xl-1"
                  style="background-size: 30px; background-position: center">
                  images
                </div>
                <span class="txt-name-file p-xl-2 text-wrap text-break mb-2 mb-xl-0 text-xl-left">{{ file.name
                  }}</span>
                <button class="btn-delete w-auto h-auto" (click)="
                    removeFileConst(file, fileUploader, 1, element.valor)
                  ">
                  <em class="fa fa-trash-o icon-btn-delete"></em>
                </button>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-container *ngIf="element.valor == documentoReformas">
              <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                <div class="text-center" id="btn-add-container" hidden>
                  <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="add()" *ngIf="this.listDocsAux[2].archivos < 4">
                    <mat-icon class="btn-add-doc">add_circle</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </ng-template>
            </ng-container>
          </p-fileUpload>
```

Comment: If you want help, show the code you have written to try and solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it doesn't work`?  Did it allow you to upload more than the limit? Did it just stop working?

Comment: It allows me more than the limit I set

Comment: When the window pop up, you can select more than the limit. Is that what you referring to?

Comment: Yes, and shows me the files